# Regular expression to detect faulty phone numbers in PHP

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I am trying to build a regular expression to detect faulty phone numbers and replace them with the original one. I have the phone number and in a text field with text (with html tags) are the faulty numbers (users of the site like to put various characters in between the number for some reason). Here is what I am using which works fine on most cases but not all:

```
$phone = '0888123123';
$text = 'Some html text with variants of the phone number in wrong format - 
0~8~8~8~1~2~3~1~2~3
0.8.8.8.1.2.3.1.2.3
0 8 8 8 1 2 3 1 2 3
0888-123-123
The last format does not work!';

preg_match_all('/('.implode('[\D]+', str_split($phone)).')/i', strip_tags($text), $matches);

if (count($matches) > 0) {
   foreach($matches as $value) {
      $text = str_replace($value, $phone, $text);
   }
}
```

I try to find any non-digit characters in between the numbers but it only works if this non-digit character is between all numbers i.e 0.8.8.8.1.2.3.1.2.3, but it does not match 0888-123-123. Is there some addition in this regular expression to catch the rest of the cases?

Comment: its easier to detect that phone no is int have certain number of digits ... or use phone no carrier lookup api (ex http://www.telapi.com/docs/api/rest/carrier-services/carrier-lookup/ ) so that you can check wheather phone no have valid carrier or not

Comment: I do that but in the phone field. Inside the text field I can't detect it because the users put it inside the HTML text.

Comment: no you can not do that .. or only possibility is that your text should contain only letters other than phone number so that you can extract numeric and than check that weather they are valid or not

Comment: just wait for a minute i cam creating an isolated example for that

Comment: you need to change `[\D]+` to `[\D]*`. Coz you want to replace text even if there is nothing b/w some of the digits... So `*`, which means 0 or more. AND `+` means 1 or more....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[^\d\n]
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nB2lL9/6

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, I didn't know about this tool, looks awesome for testing